# Запятая и тире в авторском стихотворении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп

Женская сущность
сложна, глубока, —
такова уж её природа.
Так и тайна, поэтика, красота —
в сущности женского рода.

В первом предложении я интуитивно поставила запятую и тире. Есть ли правило, объясняющее такую пунктуацию?

Comment: Елена, а во втором предложении что имеется в виду:  _в сущности женского рода_  –  грамматический род однородных подлежащих или женский пол?

Comment: Имеются в виду качества, присущие женскому полу.

Comment: Елена, а  вы не могли бы пояснить словами, в чем заключается ваша интуиция относительно постановки запятой и тире. Дело в том, что правила использования  этого знака  существуют, но они недостаточно конкретны, их применение всегда вызывает вопросы,  а обоснования не кажутся достаточно убедительными. В то же время этот знак интересен и, как  мне кажется, неслучаен. Возможно,  авторы художественных произведений также делали свой выбор в большей степени по интуиции, чем по каким-то правилам. Вот поэтому мне интересно ваше мнение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос я дам в заключительной части, а сначала это будет развернутый комментарий по теме.

**1.  Об интуитивном чувстве знака.** Такое объяснение, приведенное автором вопроса, заинтересовало меня.  Я не берусь обсуждать содержание  стихотворения (об этом не спрашивали), но чувство языка удивительное!
**Как же выглядит интуиция** в моем понимании при выборе тире или запятой и тире? Вероятно, это **семантика и интонация**. Они – разные, а вот какие?

**2.  О двойном знаке (запятая и тире).** Нет, это не авторский и не устаревший знак, для его использования есть вполне **объективные** причины. Если же он реже применяется в современных текстах, то, возможно,  меньше стало конструкций, характерных для этого знака.

**3.  А что говорит Розенталь?** Розенталь называет несколько тем, где ставится запятая и тире, но ведь что-то их связывает. Должна же быть **обобщенная идея э**того знака.  Попробуем её определить для частного варианта с местоимениями  ***так, такой, таков.***

В правилах дается интересное указание: **тире** ставится, если БСП выглядит **как субъект и предикат.** Это означает, что присоединительное предложение достаточно тесно связано с основным по смыслу. А если такая логическая  связь отсутствует, то ставится **запятая и тире**.

Поэтому двойной знак может содержать **следующую информацию:**   хотя местоимения ***так, такой, таков*** связывают два  предложения в БСП, но это  отнюдь не  тесная взаимообусловленность. Это скорее тот **«поворот мысли»,** о которой также говорится в правилах.

**4.  И теперь про интонацию.**   Обычно мы говорим о **паузах** различной длительности, но забываем  о  **тонической характеристике** (повышение или понижение голоса перед паузой).

А эта  тема вполне понятна каждому: **полное понижение** делается в конце предложения (мысль закончена, **точка** поставлена), а если будет  продолжение, то   тон в первой части повышается.  **Но есть  еще вариант**: тон в конце первой части понижается, но не полностью.

**5.  И это как раз наш случай, когда мы выбираем тире или запятую и тире.**

При постановке **тире** мы  понижаем тон, чтобы обозначить **присоединительный** характер  конструкции, но понижаем **не полностью** (иначе связь субъект – предикат будет нарушена).

А если  мы, напротив,  не хотим, чтобы предложение выглядело как субъект и предикат и нам нужно **ослабить семантическую связь**?  В этом случае мы понижаем тон  практически  **до конца**, то есть  как при постановке **точки**, только пауза будет меньше, чем в конце предложения.

Это и можно считать  **интонационным и смысловым решением при выборе двойного знака** в нашем частном случае, то есть при наличии местоимений ***так, такой, таков***.

**6. И несколько слов по поводу ответа  Александра.** Вот если бы он не торопился с ответом!  Ведь понятно, что вопрос сложный, нужна предельная внимательность во всем, в том числе при чтении правил.

Розенталь дает для этих местоимений **особое решение,** изложенное  **в двух темах**: § 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении; § 46. Запятая и тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении.

Александр  же цитирует только § 46, но даже  там желательно обратить внимание на **точку с запятой** в тексте: « …вторая часть носит присоединительный характер с каким-либо дополнительным оттенком значения (пояснительным, временным, условно-следственным и др.); **нередко** эта часть начинается местоименными словами **тот, так, такой».**  Так нужно ли вообще рассматривать **дополнительный оттенок значений** при решении этой задачи?

**Но надо отдать должное его замечанию про точку** (правда, уже в комментариях):
«...при увеличенной паузе (когда можно и точку поставить) двойной знак нормально смотрится».   **Интонационную характеристику он угадывает верно.** Вот если бы он не торопился!

**7.  Ответ на вопрос.**

***Женская сущность сложна, глубока, — такова уж её природа.***

Выбираем  не тире, а запятую и тире.  Вторая часть – это размышление на тему, заданную в первой части.  Поэтому здесь  нет отношений субъект – предикат,  то есть **нет тесной смысловой связи** между двумя частями, **интонационная** связь между предложениями также ослаблена (полное понижение голоса, более длительная пауза, чем при постановке тире).

К тому же в первой части присутствует **перечислительная интонация** для однородных членов, что также способствует **самостоятельности** двух простых предложений в составе БСП.

Comment: Замечательный ответ! Спасибо за объяснение **всех** тонкостей.

Comment: Александр, большое спасибо за оценку, ваше мнение меня особенно интересовало. К тому же вы и помогли мне предложить решение (я имею в в виду вашу фразу: при увеличенной паузе, когда можно и точку поставить, двойной знак нормально смотрится). Такой вот парадокс: точка стала исходным пунктом для рассуждений. Ну и конечно, мне помог Розенталь, я его, наверное, в первый раз так внимательно прочитала.

Comment: Sharon Благодарю Вас за искренность и неподдельный интерес.
Мой интуитивный посыл - придание большей значимости второй части предложения.
Меня поразила многогранность Вашего ответа. Я не углубляюсь в дебри правил, почтительно доверяя это лингвистам, а себя тестирую просто: нет ли грубой ошибки? Чтобы удостовериться, обратилась с вопросом.
По поводу интонации: я действительно делаю долгую "значащую" паузу, реализуя свой интуитивный посыл. И голос в конце первой части понижаю именно не полностью, оставляя предположение продолжения.

Comment: Тонику логично анализировать по звучанию, и само собой напрашивается предложение для сайта: исключительно для этого предусмотреть возможность оставлять голосовые сообщения.
При отсутствии такой возможности приятнее осознавать чуткость воспринимающего. Воодушевлена. Признательна.

Comment: @SharonУпоминание о вопросе встретилось на rus.meta.stackexchange.com, мою попытку обратиться к Вам в комментарии система отклонила.

Женская сущность сложна, глубока, —
такова уж её природа.
Так и тайна, поэтика, красота —
в сущности женского рода.

Это четверостишие появилось с целью стать эссе для афиши и эпиграфом к экспликации выставки картин кузбасских художников "essentia femina". Мне необходимо было кратко и ёмко выразить суть экспозиционной подборки. Вопрос о знаках препинания в стихотворении открыл возможность проанализировать его полностью. Крайне интересно Ваше мнение.

Comment: @Елена  Я не совсем поняла суть вашего вопроса. На Мете я писала, что слово "в сущности" желательно оформить как вводное слово, и это важно для раскрытия содержания стихотворения.  Я могу подробнее объяснить свою точку зрения.

Comment: @Sharon На Мете в размышлениях о выразительных средствах языка Вы написали: "обратила внимание на форму стиха. Само содержание тоже заинтересовало, но форма была не очень удачной, вот чуть-чуть бы подправить, а как? Заинтересовало, да, но обсудить оказалось не с кем. К тому же обсуждение выходило за рамки заданного вопроса". Это стихотворение-четверостишие, и, возможно, Ваши рассуждения о нём как о целом станут началом обсуждения на форуме средств художественной выразительности.

Comment: @Елена Вам следует задать новый вопрос, т. к. в комментариях возможности ограничены.

Comment: @Елена Я тоже хотела посоветовать вам задать новый вопрос примерно с таким названием: Нужно ли обособлять слово «в сущности»? Текст возможен следующий.  Слово «в сущности» может быть вводным словом и необособленным обстоятельством. Какой вариант  больше подходит к содержанию приведенного ниже стихотворения? Факультативным или обязательным будет такое обособление?
В этом обсуждении могут принять участие  все, кто интересуется этой темой. Я тоже дам свой ответ, но чуть позднее, чтобы не мешать высказаться другим.

Comment: @Sharon В данном стихотворении "в сущности" несёт смысловую нагрузку. Имеется в виду сущность женского пола как "природа" (натура, суть вещи или явления), которая определяет свойства, признаки: глубину, высоту и т. п. Тайна, поэтика, красота, равно как и сложность и глубина женской сущности, являются качествами женской натуры. Поэтому запятая исключена. Меня заинтересовала возможность полемики о средствах художественной выразительности на примере данного стихотворения-четверостишия. Как точнее задать вопрос?

Comment: @Елена Вероятно, я увидела в этом стихотворении нечто большее, чем то, что там действительно говорится. Даже не знаю теперь, стоит ли озвучивать мою точку зрения, мне бы не хотелось вас расстраивать какой-либо критикой. Если же говорить уклончиво, то именно обособление вводного слова давало этому содержанию, этой грамматике особую глубину и интерес (так я думаю). В моем понимании  в основе конструкции лежало уподобление (соответствие) – универсальный закон мира.  В качестве художественного приема мы постоянно видим этот закон  в сказках, в поэзии, даже в магических заговорах.

Comment: Но если ничего этого нет, то мне отвечать не имеет смысла.  
Что касается другой постановки вопроса, то у нас есть метка «литература» (можно посмотреть, о чем там спрашивали).  Или  задать вопрос напрямую: какие выразительные средства  языка использованы в данном четверостишье. Возможно, будут какие-то ответы.

Answer (score 4):

Первое предложение сложное, связь между его частями бессоюзная. Запятая и тире стоят по следующему правилу.

[**Запятая и тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_46.htm) (Розенталь)

> 2. **Запятая и тире** ставятся между двумя частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, из которых вторая носит присоединительный характер с каким-либо **дополнительным оттенком значения** (пояснительным, временным, условно-следственным и др.); нередко эта часть начинается местоименными словами ***тот, так, такой*** и т. п.:
> *Она сидела неподалёку на скамье под покосившимся деревянным грибом, — такие делают в лагерях для часовых* (Пауст.).

Вероятно, можно обойтись и без запятой перед тире. В Национальном корпусе русского языка есть следующие примеры:

*Когда-то она была очень красива — это было и сейчас видно, тем более что Ольга Георгиевна, как и все бывшие красавицы, о разрушительной работе времени просто не хотела знать ― такова уж женская природа…* [И. С. Шкловский. Новеллы и популярные статьи (1982)]

*В хорошей шутке заключены подчас довольно мудрые мысли — такова уж природа юмора.* [Б. Доценко. И рыба, и мясо! // «Химия и жизнь», 1969]

*Органически не могу тянуться в хвосте — такова уж натура.* [А. А. Авдеев. Дневник (1942)]

Comment: Спасибо, Александр.

Comment: @Елена, и Вам спасибо за вопрос. На сайте принято отмечать полезные ответы стрелочкой вверх (Вы сможете это делать, когда наберёте 15 баллов), а наиболее подходящий – ещё и галочкой слева, как принятый. Но не торопитесь — может, ещё кто-нибудь ответит.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Какой именно "дополнительный оттенок значения" вы усматриваете в этом присоединном предложении? По Розенталю в данном правиле наличие такого оттенка является необходимым для запятой и тире как единого знака. А вот у автора его не просматривается, равно как и в ваших примерах из Нацкорпуса.

Comment: @behemothus  Может, такой оттенок здесь явно не виден, поэтому после нахождения правила, которым можно объяснить постановку обоих знаков (о чём спрашивает автор), я добавил примеры из Корпуса. На мой взгляд, во всех предложениях можно задать вопрос "почему?", т. е. будет причинный оттенок. _Почему я не могу тянуться в хвосте? — Такова уж моя натура._ _Почему женская сущность глубока? – Такова уж ее природа._

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  Скажите, пожалуйста, а у вас относительно этого знака не возникают вопросы, вам всё в этой теме кажется ясным? Вас устраивают ваши собственные объяснения или все-таки остаются сомнения? Неужели авторы из Нацкорпуса  ориентировались на причинный оттенок, задавали вопрос "почему", когда выбирали двойной знак?

Comment: @Sharon Конечно, возникают. Автор спрашивала о правиле, и формально оно подходит. Но сам я, скорее, не поставил бы запятую,  поэтому и полез в Корпус,  посмотрел и удостоверился, что там много таких случаев (как раз **без двойного знака**) . Может, как авторская (интуитивная) постановка обоих знаков в данном стихотворении имеет право на жизнь?

Comment: Вы же знаете, что знаки препинания у нас ставятся по правилам, так что "интуитивное право" может быть оспорено как несостоятельное. Двойной знак отличается от тире, и хотелось бы считать его полноценным, а не авторским знаком. Я бы сделала такой вывод: мы недостаточно понимаем природу этого знака, так как ориентируемся только на семантические признаки и не учитываем грамматику, структуру и интонацию предложений. А вот авторы это интуитивно чувствуют.

Comment: Так всё-таки, по вашему мнению,  интуиция не подвела? И этот знак  согласуется с правилом?

Comment: Я бы тоже поставила здесь запятую и тире, но пока тоже по интуиции. Правила мне не слишком помогают, по-моему, они нуждаются в редактировании, но только кто их будет редактировать. А автору я ответила бы коротко, честно и без лишних подробностей о дополнительных значениях: В правилах Розенталя такой знак допускается, см.п.8 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151 К такому обоснованию претензий у редакторов,я думаю,  не будет. Кстати, а вы свою Интуицию не пробовали спрашивать? Какой бы знак поставили, если бы не читали правил?

Comment: И еще вопросик. Как вы думаете, если после "сущности" поставить запятую, то это не изменило бы стих в лучшую сторону? Было бы больше загадочности, глубины художественного пространства?

Comment: Про запятую я писал выше, что, скорее бы, не поставил, но при увеличенной паузе (когда можно и точку поставить) двойной знак нормально смотрится. А про _сущность_ я сразу задал вопрос Елене. У нее это не вводное слово, а полноправный член в сочетании _сущность рода_.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответы. Разумеется, про вводное слово всё понятно,  меня  же интересовало ваше мнение как ценителя поэзии, а совсем не  как  редактора.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли правило, объясняющее такую пунктуацию?

Правло из Розенталя вам привели, но вопрос не в правиле, а в его применимости.
Формально обосновать такой знак можно, то есть его применение явной пунктуационной ошибкой не будет, но такой выбор, на мой взгляд, типичный "авторский знак". Уточню, что под авторской пунктуацией понимается не пунктуация, противоречащая правилам, как многие думают, а вытекающая из какого-то особенного, присущего только данному автору, понимания смысла или структуры его предложения.

По правилу у Розенталя для использование запятой и тире требуется наличие какого-то дополнительного оттенка значения у присоединяемой части.

> Запятая и тире ставятся между двумя частями бессоюзного сложного
> предложения, из которых вторая носит присоединительный характер с
> каким-либо дополнительным оттенком значения (пояснительным, временным,
> условно-следственным и др.)

Я такого оттенка без контекста не усматриваю. Не видят его, судя по всему, и авторы подобных фраз из приводимых **Александр Стрелец** цитат из нацкорпуса. Причинное значение ("почему?") здесь явно не проходит, на вопрос "почему" присоединяемая часть явным образом не отвечает ("женская сущность глубока, потому что такова её природа" - это объяснение похлеще будет, чем даже "потому что гладиолус").

Если что и можно рассмотреть, то разве что некоторый усилительный оттенок, но даже этот вариант несколько портит частица "уж", которая, честно говоря, непонятно что делает в этом предложении, придавая ему какой-то уступительный смысл. *Ничего не поделаешь, глубока сущность, о чем автор искренне сожалеет.*

Короче, если автор вопреки всему сказанному видит в присоединяемой части дополнительный оттенок значения, то он может воспользоваться предлагаемым знаком. Именно для того, чтобы показать свое особое виденье.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Природа (натура, суть вещи) определяет свойства, признаки: глубину, высоту и т. п. Сложность и глубина женской сущности  обусловлены самой природой. И частица "уж" утверждает это как неоспоримый факт, как полное принятие данности.